# Angular: invoke method in child directive from parent directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0PMzJ2FcPdloqXPUtaMy?p=preview) I have two directives, a parent and a child. The child directive has a variable `scope.var` and a method that increments it. I want to call this method from the parent directive. What's the best way to do this?

Note: I don't want to $broadcast an event.

Comment: add a controller to parent directive, and require it from your child. this way child make parent aware of its existence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8q6TlaFKTuK1k0ODqzyD?p=preview).

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('parent', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: "<button ng-click='increment()'>increment</button>" + "<br/><child />"
    }
});


app.directive('child', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "{{var}}",
        controller: ["$scope", function($scope) {
            $scope.var = 0;
            $scope.increment = function() {
                $scope.var++;
            };
        }]
    };
});
```

Comment: I need to invoke a method in the child directive, that method will increment the variable

Comment: beware coupling with scope inheritance chain and won't work with controller-as pattern.

Comment: you put `{{var}}` on the main page, it should reside in the child's template

Answer (score 0):

if you need to make your child directive to do something you can use, observer, watchers or events

```
//using observe
attrs.$observe('increment',function(){
 scope.increment()
});

//using events
scope.$on('incrementChild',function(){
  scope.increment()
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LJr38fFpuUl48orZOKHa?p=preview

check this plunker is a fork of your own code

Comment: OP didn't want to use events. and both look like a hack to me.

Comment: actually is not a hack events are there to be used and foment decoupling, that way you don't need to know anything about the child directive other than the event it listens, if you want your child directive to perform an action and have isolate or inherited scope, i would say events are your best bet

Answer (score 0):

Add a controller to parent directive, and require it from your child. this way child make parent aware of its existence.

This is the proper way to create API in components. We can do a little better by removing scope still.

Parent:

```
directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.callIncrement = function () {
        // invoke increment function in child directive
        scope.childs.forEach(function (child) {
          child.increment();
        });
      };
};
directive.controller = function ($scope) {
  //debugger;
  $scope.childs = [];
  this.addChild = function (child) {
    $scope.childs.push(child);
  };
};
```

Child:

```
directive.require = '^parent';
directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {
scope.var = 0;

scope.increment = function() {
      scope.var++;
};

parentCtrl.addChild(scope);
};
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/nGiPnm3k8RzvvQhMFJ7L?p=preview

Comment: say I have parent1, parent2 and parent3 directives that use the child directive, how can I make the child independent from who's invoking the method? I cannot require from the child all the parents.

Comment: Child's always would be somehow aware of the kind of parents. Perhaps you should use a (singleton) service. Could you be more specific on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just need to invoke a method in the child directive from the parent directive

Comment: so I guess it's better to broadcast an event to decouple the parent from the child